# How to optimize when drawing many(eg 50,000) MeshRenderers or SpriteRenderers in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, renderer

Is there a way to optimize when there are so many Renderers?
The condition is that the renderers have their own animations, and each color can change.
I tried to combine several things into one, but I have a problem that the above conditions are not met.

In the image below there are 20,000 MeshRenderers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcXyM.png)

---

### [Added]

I applied dynamic placement, but only 3 to 5 frames were improved.
I used a MeshRenderer and applied Quad.

The shader uses a very simple shader that enters the color and outputs it as an emission.

[image]
[image]

```
Shader "Custom/Only Emission" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader{
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        fixed4 _Color;

        struct Input {
            float4 color;
        };

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            o.Emission = _Color.rgb;
        }
        ENDCG
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions you may want to dig in is how to comply with [Dynamic Batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) rules:

- Currently, only Mesh Renderers, Trail Renderers, Line Renderers, Particle Systems and Sprite Renderers are batched. This means that skinned Meshes, Cloth, and other types of rendering components are not batched.
- batching is applied only to Meshes containing no more than 900 vertex attributes (so if your shader is using 3 passes, your mesh can only have 300 vertices max for the batching to work)
- Batching will not work if your GameObjects don't have uniform scale.

Another way to go is to make sure that you're using a [GPU Instantiated](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html) material. GPU Instancing only renders identical Meshes with each draw call, but each instance can have different parameters (for example, color or scale) to add variation and reduce the appearance of repetition.

And finally, yes [combining meshes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) in runtime might help in some cases. But it will make your occlusion culling setup break as looking at just one part will also render the non-visible parts.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I applied dynamic batching but there was no big performance improvement. I added information.

Comment: is your material support GPU instancing ?